# Past tense for smite

Tags: system-agnostic, terminology

Odd question. I got into a debate with someone over smite and its various forms of tense (future, past, and current). The dictionary says smote is past tense. For years I have been using smited. Is smited more a gaming usage or am I just plain wrong? Does it even matter what gaming system its in?

Comment: I’m... not sure how to answer this. If the answer is “yes,” an example could be provided (though the question seems to be asking about all RPGs ever), but if the answer is “no” I don’t see how on earth that could be demonstrated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about conjugating English language verbs and not about RPGs.

Comment: @ObliviousSage My first quick reading led me to think the same, but it's definitely about RPG-specific usage.

Comment: How many RPG's use "smite" as a special thing other than the English word, and do any of them write the past form as "smited"? I don't think I've ever heard "smited" used except as someone guessing wrongly what the past form is. But the games I play don't really have smiting as a special thing, except for Dominons, which is Swedish.

Comment: I suspect many uses of "smited" are an attempt to turn the verb into an adjective via past participle, not as a past tense per se - "When the paladin hits with a smite, the smited target..."  In this case, however, "smitten" is correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The past tense is *smote*, as you've noted. You can also say someone's been *smitten*, but that just as often means "in love", so use with caution or to comedic effect.

*Yes,* "smited" is just plain incorrect. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smote%2Csmited&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csmote%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmote%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSmote%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csmited%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmited%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSmited%3B%2Cc0) pegs its usage in books at 0%. It's just a colloquialism resulting from poor understanding of the word's tenses, not a gaming term. Gaming circles are one of the places you'll encounter the word "smite" a lot, so naturally you'll encounter incorrect past tenses of it there a lot as well.

**Does the gaming system matter?** Since there's [several thousand RPGs](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-just-dont-understand-the-scope-of-the-rpg-landscape), we can't really answer that. (Sure, maybe, somewhere it matters?) But more to the point, what some vague RPG somewhere happens to do shouldn't really matter to you unless it's *your* game system. If you're self-conscious about it, check whether your books use "smote" or "smitten" and go with that. The important thing is, presumably, that other people understand what you mean. And, well, all three words, even the incorrect "smited", will do that.

If you want to be gramatically correct *as well as* communicating clearly, or to stop having your language choices irk your companion, use "smote" or "smitten".

(If you want to infuriate them, use "smoted.")

Comment: The [Google Ngram of *smote* vs. *smited*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smote%2Csmited&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csmote%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmote%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSmote%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csmited%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmited%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSmited%3B%2Cc0) might be of interest. (I didn't include *smitten* because its use is almost entirely in a different context that's not meaningfully comparable.)

Comment: Yeah, smitten is not the verb you are looking for

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks! Nice one. Those are some striking results.

Comment: As mentioned in @agpoweredmag's answer, "smitten" is perfect tense, not past tense.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to that question would be [smote](https://www.wordnik.com/words/smote), it's a past tense/past participle of smite. To the best of my knowledge **smited** isn't a *real* word. It doesn't take much beyond a cursory search to find this for your self.

[The Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/smite-smote-smitten/), one of my favorite grammar resources has a page devoted to smite. See the excerpt below:

> The verb smite, meaning to inflict a heavy blow, is traditionally
>   inflected smote (in the past tense) and smitten (in the perfect tense
>    and as a past participle).1 Some dictionaries list smited as an
>   alternative past-tense form, but it has always been far less common than smote in published writing.

Comment: The querent obviously knows this; they say it in the question! What they're asking is if RPGs, collectively or individually, use a non-standard conjugation. Can you edit your answer to address that, please?